# Conditional compilation in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to do conditional compilation in TypeScript using #if, #endif directives for example? I wish I was able to enable/disable tracing.

Answer (score 9):

There isn't currently, but vote for the [feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3538) so that it makes it in someday!

Answer (score 7):

You can use `global_defenitions` option of UglifyJs for doing this. For example if you pass:

```
global_defs: {
    DEBUG: false
}
```

the compressor will assume that's a constant defintion and will discard code like this as being unreachable:

```
if (DEBUG) {
   ...
}
```

Docs: 
http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/compress

Answer (score 5):

You can't do compile time directives.  The best option is to define a tracing method including all the calls to it and to turn it on define it for real and to turn it off define the method as a null op (`function () {}`). You'll still have the overhead of the method call at runtime, but it's method call to an empty method--little overhead.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR:** No, use [MSBuild conditions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szfhaft.aspx) as a manual workaround

There are no conditionals in typescript, however if you are like me, you would be fine with an ugly (but stable) workaround to achieve compile time conditionals.

In case you are developing typescript outside of visual studio, you can use something like the C preprocessor in a build step before the typescript compiler runs. You probably knew this.

If you are in visual studio, it's not that simple (could be done, but it's cumbersome).
Instead you can use [MSBuild conditional constructs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164307.aspx) in your project and a bit of javascript abuse to achieve a similar effect.

The following snippet assumes you have the configurations `Debug` and `Release` and the two files `Config.Release.ts` and `Config.Debug.ts`.

- to include it, unload your project (`right click` -> `Unload project`)
- then open it as xml (`right click` -> `Edit foo.csproj`).
- remove the conditional items (`Config.(Release|Debug).ts`) from the unconditional item group
- add the snippet below the unconditional item group

```
<Choose>
  <When Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='Debug' ">
    <ItemGroup>
      <TypeScriptCompile Include="Config.Debug.ts" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </When>
  <Otherwise>
    <ItemGroup>
      <None Include="Config.Debug.ts" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Otherwise>
</Choose>
<Choose>
  <When Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='Release' ">
    <ItemGroup>
      <TypeScriptCompile Include="Config.Release.ts" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </When>
  <Otherwise>
    <ItemGroup>
      <None Include="Config.Release.ts" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Otherwise>
</Choose>
```

This will compile one file or the other based on which configuration you are using, so you can conditionally 'patch in' the tracing behavior (or disable it).

```
// Config.Release.ts
/// <reference "Trace.ts" />
module Config {
    import TraceService = Trace.TraceService;
    TraceService.trace = function(msg: string) {}
}

// Config.Debug.ts
/// <reference "Trace.ts" />
module Config {
    import TraceService = Trace.TraceService;
    TraceService.trace = function(msg: string) { console.log(msg); }
}
```

This technique is cumbersome and requires manual patching of the `proj` file, but it's stable and it works OK until the TypeScript devs give in to popular demand or Visual Studio decides to add a precompiler which works well with MSBuild.

**Update**

It's been over a year since I created this hack, but the situation has not changed. TypeScript is still reluctant to introduce conditional compilation and that is not likely to change.
Please note that this workaround as it is does not work for projects with a `tsconfig.json`.
If there is a `tsconfig.json` in the root of the project, all the `<TypeScriptCompile/>` directives are ignored and only the `tsconfig.json` defines what gets compiled and what doesn't.
Of course the solution to that problem is multiple `tsconfig.json` files and *more MSBuild voodoo*.

If you need that and can't figure out how to do it yourself, drop a comment.

Comment: +1 However, the equality comparisons should use a double equals (at least in VS2015) otherwise the project won't open. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164282.aspx)

Comment: @EddPorter Thanks for spotting that

Comment: Does this answer still hold true in 2019?  Should I use this approach or have they come up with a non-hacky solution?

Comment: @oyalhi In short: this answer still holds true.

Answer (score 2):

There is not. Since comments are preserved during compilation, you can use a separate tool in your build process to emulate this.

Comment: Maybe it's possible to write an unobtrusive wrapper around tsc that uses webpack or just babel. It would effectively be a drop-in replacement for `tsc` in package scripts.